# how do I write a line number divisible by 3 in bash from an input file?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, printing, grep

Create a shell script which prints the line contents when the line number is divisible by 3 from an input file. Assume the first line is line 1. At the end of the script, if the total number of lines divisible by 3 is greater than 10, print “big”. Otherwise, print “small”.

So far this is what I have

```
echo $1
file=$1

awk 'NR%2==0' $file

count=$(wc -l $file | grep -o "^[0-9]")
if [ $count -gt 20 ]
then
   printf "\nbig\n"
else
   printf "\nsmall\n"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` solution. I have deliberately kept it simple.

```
$ cat awkfile
BEGIN {
   count = 0;
}

NR % 3 == 0 {
   count++
   print
}

END {
   print ""
   if (count > 10)
      print "big"
   else
      print "small"
}
```

Invoke as:

```
$ awk -f awkfile infile
```

Answer (score 1):

This Perl one-liner does the job:

```
perl -ane 'next if $.%3;$c++;print}{print($c>10?"big\n":"small\n")' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
perl -ane           # invoque perl compiler

'
  next if $.%3;     # next record if num_line modulo 3 is different than zero
  $c++;             # increment counter
  print             # print current line
  }{                # end of process
  print(            # print
    $c>10?          # if counter > 10
    "big\n"             # print "big" and newline
    :               # else
    "small\n"           # print "small" and newline
  )                 # end print
' 

file                # file to be processed
```